# 'module' object is not callable in a gan project on mnist dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, torchvision

creating a GAN using torch got TypeError: 'module' object is not callable while enumerating loader this is the code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
```

```
dataset = datasets.MNIST(root="dataset/",transform = transforms,download = True)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = batch_size,shuffle = True)
```

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch_idx, (real, _) in enumerate(loader):
        real = real.view(-1, 784).to(device)
```

this the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\utkar\PycharmProjects\simpleGAN\main.py", line 57, in <module>
    for batch_idx, (real, _) in enumerate(loader):
  File "C:\Users\utkar\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 628, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\utkar\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 671, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\utkar\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 58, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\utkar\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 58, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\utkar\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py", line 145, in __getitem__
    img = self.transform(img)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: The `transform` argument to `MNIST` has to be a callable (e.g. a function or class), you handed in the `torchvision.transforms` module from your imports. You may want to use something from inside that module instead.

Comment: What specific transform do you want to apply? Currently you are simply passing the entire torchvision.transforms module, not a specific transform.